# Getting unique id's Bank program java

Tags: java, class, random

I'm creating a bank program and hava classes `Account` (abstract), `SavingsAccount` and `Customer` (among others). When I create a new `savingsaccount` I want to get an id to each account. My problem is the I can't figure out how to make the id unique.

What else am I missing? How can I work with the `ArrayList` for customers and accounts? Any other suggestions? This is very difficult for me, but I'm trying hard to learn and to understand.

In Bank class I create a couple of customers c1 and c2. I then create two accounts for customer c1.

```
public class Bank {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Customer> customerList = new ArrayList<Customer>();  
    ArrayList<Account> accountList = new ArrayList<Account>();  

    Customer c1 = new Customer("John");
    Customer c2 = new Customer("Sam");        

    SavingsAccount a1 = new SavingsAccount(c1);
    SavingsAccount a2 = new SavingsAccount(c1);

    customerList.add(c1);
    customerList.add(c2);              

    accountList.add(a1);
    accountList.add(a2); 
    } 
}
```

In Account class:

```
public abstract class Account {  
   protected int balance;
   protected int id;
   protected double interest;
   protected Customer name;

   public Account() {}

   public Account(Customer name) {
   this.name = name;
   }

   public abstract void deposit(int amount); 

   public abstract void withdraw(int amount);

   public abstract int getBalance();

   public abstract void transfer(int amount, Account account);
}
```

In class SavingsAccount:

```
public class SavingsAccount extends Account{ 
    public SavingsAccount() {
        super();
    }

    SavingsAccount(Customer person) {
        name = person;
        id = (int) Math.floor(Math.random()*101);  //This won't generate a unique number for each savingsaccount
    }  
}
```

Comment: if you don't store your uid in a form (as pronounced answer #1 from Vaishak Suresh) it' not guaranteed to be a unique id - it's rather not likely but not guaranteed - but you can use a simple text file instead of a database, if you do code just for practice (well in that case UUID would fit you either... so never mind my hints...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing in the code is getting a pseudo random number in the range 0 through 101. This does not ensure that the numbers are not going to be repeated. Some ways to ensure unique id generation are

1. If you're using a database, have an auto increment number generated by the database
2. Have a static variable in the code that you increment each time you assign an ID
3. Write some form of hash function that generates an integer ID based on the Customer object.
4. Use [UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) to generate unique IDs too. This also lets you compute it randomly and get hash for the ID etc.

Comment: Thank you. At first I had an idea of saving numbers from 1-100 in a list and then (somehow) pick numbers from the list. I will try your suggestion number two instead.

Comment: 5. Use a simple cipher to encrypt 0, 1, 2, 3, ... etc.  Because cyphers are reversible the outputs are guaranteed to be unique for unique inputs.

Comment: I don't consider #3 an option, even accepting (requiring?) equal IDs for equal `Customer objects`: hash functions are not required to be injective, and more often than not, standard ones map unlimited input to a finite set of values - think birthday paradox.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse math random give you a random number but not unique ... use UUID.randomUUID().toString()

Comment: Ok, I will try to learn about UUID.randomUUID().toString().
Thank you